# Split string by months as delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I'm trying to take in a txt file of messages sent and split it into a list at every occurrence of a date.

Example:

```
'Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi'
```

Would become

```
['Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello', 'Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi']
```

After doing some research it looks like I need to use the re.split() but I'm not sure how to use it. I tried this:

```
import re
def getFile(file):
    infile=open(file, 'r')
    content=infile.read()
    return content

def cleanup(file):
    messages = getFile(file)    
    m=messages.replace('\n',' ')
    print(m)
    months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov']
    print(re.split('Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov', m))
```

But it doesn't give me what I want.

How should I format it so it does what I need it to do?

Comment: You might like to tighten the regex to exclude false-positives like 'Martial' or 'Octagonal'. In your case you know the 3-letter month abbreviation is followed by whitespace then 1+ digits then whitespace then 4-digit YYYY. You can use a lookahead assertion to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `re.split` as well:

```
>>> import re
>>> months=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
>>> s = 'Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi'
>>> rx = re.compile( fr"\s+(?=(?:{'|'.join(months)})\b)", re.I )
>>> print (rx)
re.compile('\\s+(?=(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\\b)', re.IGNORECASE)
>>>
>>> print (rx.split(s))
['Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello', 'Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi']
```

**[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/qgaWDM)**

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces that asserts next lookahead condition
- `(?=`: Start lookahead condition

  - `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\\b`: Match 3 letter month name followed by a word boundary
- `)`: End lookahead
- `re.I`: Enable ignore case match

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the regex with `"()"`, it will also capture the delimiter you're splitting by (in this case, the month name).

For instance,

```
>>> s = "Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi"
... pattern = r"\b(Aug)\b"
... xs = re.split(pattern, s)
... xs = [(a + b).rstrip() for a, b in zip(xs[1::2], xs[2::2])]

>>> xs
['Aug 5 2020: John Doe: Hello', 'Aug 5 2020 Jane Doe: Hi']
```

A more general pattern that works with all months can be built:

```
>>> months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
...           'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
>>> pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(months)})\b"

>>> pattern
r'\b(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\b'
```

As @smci suggests, a more strict regex may be formed via:

```
>>> pattern = fr"(\b(?:{'|'.join(months)}) \d{{1,2}} \d{{4}}\b)"

>>> pattern
r'(\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2} \d{4}\b)'
```

This forces us to require a day and year after the month. `"(?:month)"` denotes a non-capturing group so that `re.split` doesn't pick up redundant substrings.